# I am not able to figure out what changes have i made in selenium. It is not working and throwing some error. (Selenium - Java- BigSur)

Tags: java, macos, selenium, macos-big-sur

```
package testsel;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    "/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Error:

```
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: line 1: �PNG
: command not found
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: line 2: : command not found
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `�}�=OA���J�Q��ŕ4*'
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: command substitution: line 3: `�1���*iCCPSkia(�}�=OA���J�Q��ŕ4*'
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: line 3: ���mg{�j�U�e[����-�cjHH: Illegal byte sequence
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/Users/sumitjadhav/Documents/chromedriver: line 5: `8$�O��lc��M�e[n��Uٕ������r��ǙY��-��3�+��~P�9�yN�:��[�,��Ydddd��@DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDt����X�!,)q�@DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDt�b�������������������J`U�,"""""""""""""""""�*1�EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDT%���������������������Q��""""""""""""""""""�XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDUb�������������������J`U�,"""""""""""""""""�*1�EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDT%���������������������Q��""""""""""""""""""�XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDUb�������������������J`U�,"""""""""""""""""�*1�EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDT%���������������������Q��""""""""""""""""""�XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDUb�������������������J`U�,"""""""""""""""""�*1�EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDT%���������������������Q��""""""""""""""""""�XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDUb�������������������J`U�,"""""""""""""""""�*1�EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDT%���������������������Q��""""""""""""""""""�XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDUb�������������������J`U�,"""""""""""""""""�*1�EDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDT%���������������������Q��""""""""""""""""""����8�X`Y,X(��r� � ,�|X,�:���,���� D{��0���o��ƍ��J�JCX�y��iY����.����Ճp��sF����>,˂e��?���<w�I��R�>V˴`Z������Z֩��~��1D� @E��όJ�|���ǜ'c�A��{�̕�������������h�1����@�����0�iAO�ۂ��v���t~��fP"X���۩��T �d���p�a"�+ WP��&ô���N9*cY,��p(2E�8�5�\s-�fʡI!IY�,IPdi��q�1X��"2�"t݀��Sa�z��v� ��-���l�z0L�<�'
Mar 13, 2021 2:35:52 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'Sumits-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:43b:9205:195b:649c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at testsel.abc.main(abc.java:11)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:42218/status] to be available after 20018 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: I don't think MacOS has a `D:` drive...

Comment: Anyway, please don't post screenshots of your code. Please [edit] your question to include your code as text.